# Dialogfragment isn't clearing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Via a button I'm popping a DialogFragment (per Google's developer doc's) which contains a RadioGroup.  On the DialogFragment I'm populating the RadioGroup with an array of RadioButtons.

My problem is that when I hit the back key on the DialogFragment, then hit the button to pop the DialogFragment again, the array of RadioButtons is acting as if the previous array is still present (and the new RadioButton index/ID values are double the previous ones).

My suspicion is that my layout in the DialogFragment is using the main activity's context and therefore the DialogFragment isn't "fresh" the 2nd time in, but I can't track it down.  Any conceptual advice would be wonderful.

Edit:  Specifically the checkedId of the RadioGroup doubles each time I go in and out of the DialogFragment:
    `.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){`

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: To help me learn I was hoping to keep this conceptual.  I can post code if it will help, but it's boilerplate code from the Developer doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html and the DialogFragment code itself is straightforward (I'm doing my layout in onCreateView).  What I'm hoping for is some hints such as:  Should a DialogFragment open up completely fresh each time it's popped from the same Activity/Fragment?  How can I make sure the entire DialogFragment layout clears when I hit the back button on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the Id's of the radiobuttons.

Comment: I tried that but zero is the only id it will let me manually add.  I have 14 radiobuttons.  The first time in, I'll check one towards the end and the checkedId is 10 (for example).  Then I hit back, go back into the DialogFragment, click the same radiobutton, and the checkedId is now 20.